# How to make Eclipse to automatically free the port after stopping the application?

Tags: spring, eclipse, port

Every time I stop my Spring Boot web application in Eclipse, Eclipse does not free the port so I have to do it by myself by using the following CMD commands:

netstat -aon | findstr {portnumber}

taskkill /F /PID {tasknumber}

This gets very frustrating, because I have to do it every single time. Is there any way for the Eclipse to manage this automatically for me, so there are no additional steps between stopping the application in the IDE and rerunning it?

Comment: That's not supposed to happen. If you stop the application in Eclipse, it sends a signal to the process to stop, and normally a spring web application handles that correctly. But if the process id is still there, it means that it is still running.

Can you show us the 'main()' method? Did you start another background thread somewhere?

Comment: Also, after you tried to stop the application via Eclipse, can you do a threaddump and take a look which thread are still running and/or waiting?
"jstack -l {pid}"

Comment: '@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.some.package1", "com.some.package2"})
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class MyApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
 }
} '

Comment: This is my main method.

Comment: I had to add that stopping the application via the command line, does not make any of those problems. But I can not use debugging tools while running with CMD, so I need to use Eclipse.

Comment: According to the output of 'jstack -l ' there seem to be 17 threads running. How can I stop them with Eclipse?

Comment: I can't remember if eclipse sends a SIGINT or SIGTERM to the application, and what the difference is with a Ctrl-C on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Image shows the red button in the console which you have to click to stop the process]

Click on the red button to free up the port and run your web application again.